# How could I show how wide a piece of furniture is?

Tags: photography-basics, smartphone, perspective

There's this strikingly wide bed that I want to take a photo of, but I can't quite find an angle that shows this. I tried placing an object (cat) for reference/comparison, but that doesn't show it either. A closer crop made it seem a little wider.

[image: Wide bed with cat]

What other ways of photographing this bed would illustrate how large (esp. wide) it is? I don't have measurements for it, but I bet it's Eastern King or larger.

My camera is a [Samsung S22 Ultra](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s22_ultra_5g-11251.php).

Comment: Add more cats to show how big it is.

Comment: A panorama shot from the front while having a pocket rule parallel to the front?

Answer (score 3):

Using a wide lens is going to make the far end appear farther way, the lines to a vanishing point are at a sharp angle. The downside of this is it might make some people think the entirety of the apparent width is due to the very short lens itself, which could be counter-productive.
Looking at the lens options on that phone, the 23mm is a bit short, the 70mm is going to have you standing in the next room, so you might be stuck, unless there's a convenient door behind you. It still might look more 'compressed' than you'd like. A 35mm or 50mm would look more 'real'. Otherwise all you can do is use the 23mm & step back as far as you can, crop later.

You could just lay a human across the bed instead, maybe even corner to corner, so you can easily see where their feet are - of course, no-one's going to be able to tell at a glance whether they're 5'2" or 6'2" but it might give a hint. People are generally very good at determining the 'reality' of perspective from photos of humans.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can toy with the panorama setting of your camera? If it's about the width I would take the photo from the foot-end of the bed.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve often used object(s) of known size to illustrate images.
A yard stick and or an extensible measuring tape placed on the object for the photograph will make the ‘reality’ more apparent.

Comment: not very natural to have a yardstick lying on a bed though ;) if "natural" is the look that the photographer is going for

Answer (score 2):

Just me, but consider using the ultrawide lens, and shooting across the surface, from the edge of the bed, opposite the cat at the other end, rather than trying to frame to get the entire bed in the shot.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to @inkista I'd advise shooting low-angle with wide lens..

But if I'm correctly understanding your goal as to **emphasize the bed's width** - I'd also suggest making the photo more from the front than the side (maybe diagonally from one of the front's corners or fully frontal). It should "widen" optically the bed (imagine bed's surface in similar angle as lake's surface shot from shore).

This small cat could be placed in the foreground along the bed edge either on top or below it (if full front wall of bed could fit in the photo) and be used for size reference (IMHO in the current picture it seems kind of lost in the background)

As none of the dimensions are given, and I don't know the size of the room, it's hard to be more specific. Maybe shooting from the opposite direction of the bedside cabinet could show more of the room and give more interesting results?

Try to make a dozen photos with different angles and distances from the bed and choose the one that suits your needs best. I hope some of this answer will be at least a bit helpful - good luck :)